# Apache: How to rewrite some dynamic URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, ip-address

I need to rewrite some specific URL's on my website but cannot find out how to do it despite searching for quite some time.

The original url that needs to be matched is in this format:
http://www.example.com/gallery/?level=picture&id=49

and I need them to be in this format:
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=gallery&level=picture&id=49

However, the folder also contains some image files as well. I need any URL's pointing directly to images to be left alone, and any URL's pointing to a php page to be rewritten as above.

I know what I want to do, but not how to do it. Basically I need to do this in .htaccess:

```
if(url contains 'gallery/' AND filetype != bmp/jpg/png/etc){
REPLACE '/gallery/' WITH '/index.php?page=gallery&' AND append original query string variables
}
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anyone that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found a solution that has taken care of this problem for me. I have this working in my .htaccess file now.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(bmp|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$
RewriteRule ^gallery/$ /index.php?page=gallery [R=302,QSA]
```

The first line (from what I have been told) excludes the file types listed from being affected by this rule, because as I originally mentioned I did not want the URL rewritten for images.

The second line takes a url like this:
    http://www.yoursite.com/gallery/?level=picture&id=52

and turns it in to this:
    http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?page=gallery&level=picture&id=52

and it leaves the original query string in place, in addition to the new "page=gallery" variable. It also does a 302 redirect so that the user is shown the correct address in their browser.

Not sure if this is helpful to anyone, but figured that since I posted asking about it, that I would post the solution I found as well.

Answer (score 0):

This may a bit more general than you want, but it'll also avoid rewriting other existing files.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^/gallery/(.+)$    index.php [QSA]
```

Comment: When you said "but it'll also avoid rewriting other existing files", what exactly did you mean? Also, would this rule match urls for all files except images?

Also, not only does it need to append the original query string, but also add a variable as well, as mentioned in my example. Is it possible to change the index.php in the second line of your code to index.php?page=gallery and then append the original query string?